# VBA Ranking Criteria Macro - Else Without If Error

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, rank

I am trying to make a macro that returns a given rank depending on the value in a cell. The value it is based on (B24) would determine the ranking and place it in B26. Below is the ranking and the code I am using. Ex. Values with over 2B should result in "1". How can I get this to work? I am currently getting "Compile error: Else without if"

```
Sub Criteria()

On Error GoTo catch_error

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Dim score As Integer, result As String
score = Range("B24").Value

If score > 2000000000 Then result = "1"

ElseIf score >= 1500000000 And score <= 1999999999.99 Then result = "2"

ElseIf score >= 500000000 And score <= 1499999999.99 Then result = "3"

ElseIf score >= 250000000 And score <= 499999999.99 Then result = "4"

ElseIf score < 249999999.99 Then result = "Out Of Scope"

result = Range("B26").Value

Exit Sub

catch_error:
MsgBox "Some Error Occurred"
End Sub
```

Comment: Now that you have three answers, It is your duty to choose **one** to be the "Correct" answer.  You choose it by clicking on the check mark by the answer.  Choose the one that you deem as the most helpful and/or the one you used.  By choosing an answer as correct it will close this question has being answered and remove it from the unanswered queue.  Do not mistake this as request to choose mine.  I just added one thing to the already great answers and will not get my feelings hurt if you choose another's.

Answer (score 1):

1. Write "End if" on the line before result = Range("B26")...
2. `Dim score As Double`, not as Integer, your values are too high and they are not integers.
3. This should be reversed:

   Range("B26").Value = result

Comment: Quick question -- Let's say I have to choose between two cells. If one is empty, use the other to determine the rank. What would I have to do? ex. B26 or B28

Comment: something like this - https://gist.github.com/Vitosh/b8ce6b24b0e253be0d91ef7aa90279f5

Answer (score 1):

A single line `If` statement can't have an `Else`:

```
If score > 2000000000 Then result = "1"
```

You need to restructure it like this:

```
If score > 2000000000 Then
    result = "1"
ElseIf score >= 1500000000 And score <= 1999999999.99 Then
    result = "2"
ElseIf score >= 500000000 And score <= 1499999999.99 Then
    result = "3"
ElseIf score >= 250000000 And score <= 499999999.99 Then
    result = "4"
ElseIf score < 249999999.99 Then
    result = "Out Of Scope"
End If
```

Comment: @ismphoto123 - `Dim score As Double`

Comment: That's how I fixed it. Thanks!!

Comment: Quick question -- Let's say I have to choose between two cells. If one is empty, use the other to determine the rank. What would I have to do? ex. B26 or B28

Comment: @ismphoto123 - `If IsEmpty(Range("B26").Value) Then score = Range("B28").Value Else score = Range("B26").Value`

Comment: thank you so much for your help. unfortunately, If both B26 and B28 are not filled in, it says Out of Scope. If they are both filled in, it only uses B28

Comment: @ismphoto123 - Just modify the test to fit your requirement then.  I simply don't have enough information about your data or expected results to determine what you need.

Comment: @ismphoto123 New questions need their own post.  Russian Doll questions are frowned upon here.  Please attempt on your own then post a new question with what you have tried and where it fails.  As to this question it has been answered.  Please choose one as correct.

Answer (score 1):

As to what the others said:

1. You cannot use a single line if with Else or Else if
2. Score needs to be a double
3. The last line is reversed.

and to add

4. The less than arguments are not needed as once the if statment finds a true it stops looking.

Code:

```
Sub Criteria()

On Error GoTo catch_error

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim score As Double, result As String
    score = .Range("B24").Value

    If score > 2000000000 Then
        result = "1"
    ElseIf score >= 1500000000 Then
        result = "2"
    ElseIf score >= 500000000 Then
        result = "3"
    ElseIf score >= 250000000 Then
        result = "4"
    Else
        result = "Out Of Scope"
    End If

    .Range("B26").Value = result

    Exit Sub
 End With
catch_error:
    MsgBox "Some Error Occurred"

End Sub
```